# Актуальные способы защиты формы от спама

Tags: php, form, спам

Здравствуйте.
Копаясь в сети по тайтлу, постоянно попадаются одни и те же способы, которые датируются от 2004 до 2018 года. Хотелось бы узнать, действительно ли боты всё ещё не проходят способы придуманные так давно? В основном предлагаются решения вроде "задержки на отправку", скрытые поля, сравнение данных.

В данный момент сам собираю форму по частям для лендинга и капча в такую форму не входит. Пока что ограничился формой:

```
<div class="main-form">
<form id="main_form" name="main_form" action="" method="post">
<div class="main-form__item">
<input class="txt_field" id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Имя">
<input class="txt_field phone_mask" id="phone" name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Телефон*">
<input type="hidden" id="url2" name="url2" value=""> // Получение url для вставки в письмо(value заполняет jQuery)
<input type="hidden" id="pagetitle" name="pagetitle" value=""> // Получение title для вставки в письмо(value заполняет jQuery)
<input type="text" id="website" name="website"> // Скрытое поле для ботов
</div>
<div class="main-form__btn">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary main_form__submit-btn" id="main_form--submit">Отправить заявку</button>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

*Наверняка можно не делать 3 лишних поля, но я пока не знаю можно ли сделать короче.*

В самом же **sendmail.php** всё что есть это проверка скрытого поля, которая не выглядит слишком-то надёжной.

```
if(!empty($_POST['website'])) die();
```

Дальше проверка заполнено ли поле phone и обработка данных с последующей отправкой.

Буду благодарен любой помощи и наводкам в этом вопросе. Это не страница с огромной аудиторией и супер-изощрённые способы не нужны. Просто хочется узнать, чем сейчас пользуются ботоводы и как можно сократить спам до нескольких писем в месяц(или совсем).

Comment: Google Invisible recaptcha. Места не занимает, спама ноль.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, но ведь по сути это старая ReCAPTCHA с одним условием: если гугл считает вас человеком, он возвращает OK без необходимости что-либо вводить и нажимать, в противном случае всё равно придётся "собирать картинки". К тому же, капча будет показываться всем, кто не авторизован в гугле.

Comment: Ну да, в этом и задача - заставить бота собирать картинки. А насчёт авторизации в Гугл - чепуха. Неизвестно, откуда вы её взяли.